# In Google Analytics how do you track page stats over a time period when your pages changed URLs?

Tags: google-analytics, url, analytics

we recently revamped about 90 pages on our website. MAJOR changes to increase conversions and user retention. We also redirected the pages to better search engine friendly (SEF) URLs.

In Google Analytics, since the switch, and since the URL has changed I have two different sets of data based on the page and am not able to do comparisons on the time on page, bounce rate, exit, etc.

Anybody have any thoughts on this or could point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't quite understand the text in your question. However, I can answer the title. No, you cannot track 301 redirects in Analytics, since the browser doesn't execute any JavaScript when loading a 301 page.

Comment: You'd have to pull up reports of the data pre URL changes and compare these against the post URL changes in a separate report if you are wanting to compare how the new pages/URL's perform against the old pages/old URL's if I understand correctly?